# Cannot properly complete flip 3D animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to make a flip 3D animation with jQuery (Transit) but I'm unable to correctly flip the content of the card.

**CSS**:

```
.flip-back {

    z-index: 300;
    background-color: #f0d6a3;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-back, .flip-front {

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.flip-container {

    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
}

.flip-content {

    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.flip-front {

    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 600;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 text-center flip-container">
    <div class="flip-content">
        <div class="flip-front">
            Front                    
        </div>
        <div class="flip-back">
            Back
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$('.flip-container').mouseenter( function() {

    $(this).children('.flip-content').transition({rotateY: '180deg'});
});
$('.flip-container').mouseleave( function() {

    $(this).children('.flip-content').transition({rotateY: '0deg'});
});
```

The problem is that when I try to animate the flip only the front is flipped and the back is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I just had to add

```
-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
-ms-transform-style:preserve-3d;
-o-transform-style:preserve-3d;
transform-style:preserve-3d;
```

in the `.flip-content` CSS class to solve the problem.